# OF macro in iowin32.h

Tags: c, winapi, window, zlib

I can't understand the following line from minizip's iowin32.h:

```
void fill_win32_filefunc OF((zlib_filefunc_def* pzlib_filefunc_def));
```

([Source](http://www.httrack.com/src/minizip/iowin32.h.html), outdated but still relevant)

What does the `OF` macro do?

Comment: Trace back through the included headers (from iowin32.c) and you'll eventually get to the definition of OF() (it's in zconf.h from zlib). I can't explain what it does though.

Comment: It's for old C (K&R) C-compilers that don't use/support function declarations I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The name `OF` might be an abbreviation for `Old function declaration`.

In the old times of the 80s and even earlier, a typical declaration for this function looked like this:

```
fill_win32_filefunc();
```

That's it. No explicit return type, no declared parameters. The return type is `int` by default, and the parameters don't matter, since the caller will (hopefully) pass in the values of the right data types anyway.

Later versions introduced the `void` type, so the declaration could look like this:

```
void fill_win32_filefunc();
```

And when ANSI C89 came out, it introduced the declaration of function parameters. Now a good declaration looked like this:

```
void fill_win32_filefunc(zlib_filefunc_def* pzlib_filefunc_def);
```

In the time early after 1989, there was a lot of code that needed to combine the two styles. Therefore a macro `OF` (or sometimes `_P` or of another name) was invented. Its definition is usually:

```
#if PRE_ANSI_C89
#  define OF(args) ()
#else
#  define OF(args) args
#endif
```

From that, both versions are generated easily.

Nowadays, this hack is not needed anymore, except for very very old compilers.